A movie about a Doctor who has affair with nanny who ends up killing his wife
I saw this movie while on vacation. 
The mother is killed by the nanny. The mother's sister figures it out: the nanny was the dad's lover (hired as a nanny to continue the affair). The dad, who is a doctor met her while traveling for a conference and brought her home as a nanny. 
I don't remember much else. I saw it on HBO. I thought the title had the world 'affair' in it or 'secret' or something but I went on IMDB and checked out most of those titles and no luck. I saw it in June 2011 or June 2010. Not sure which one.
Please help identify this, I never got to finish it and its been haunting me for years

Here's a possible match, with one difference: Perfect Alibi from 1995 with Teri Garr. It's about a doctor with a rich wife who gets a French nanny and has an affair with her. The wife's sister suspects them and concludes that they plan to kill the wife... and the nanny then kills the sister. I'm not sure if the wife dies or not. Here's a rather long clip (that also stars George's mom from Seinfeld!)

This could also be The Hand That Rocks the Cradle. It's wrong in the that doctor met her while travelling. Beyond that it seems pretty much the same...

Doctor has an affair with her (not the same)
Woman pretends to be nanny
Takes over mothers role
Tries to kill woman (although I think she gets killed by a fence)

It could be wrong...
